# Equivalent form of Arrays.asList with data from database

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I'm receiving data from the database as a string of items e.g `"Nike, Adidas, Reebok"`

`String data = "Nike, Adidas, Reebok";`

I have an algorithm that takes in  a list with the method shown below:

```
itemSetList.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Nike", "Adidas","Reebok")));
```

The variable `itemSetList` is of the form:

```
List<Set<String>> itemsetList;
```

Initialized as:

```
itemSetList = new ArrayList<>();
```

How do I change the value obtained in the String `data = "Nike, Adidas, Reebok"` to the form `"Nike", "Adidas", "Reebok"` so as to add it to the itemSetList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your input string using the delimiter `,\\s?`, wrap each shoe with quotes, and then form a set using the resulting array.

```
String data = "Nike, Adidas, Reebok";
String[] shoes = data.split(",\\s?");
for (int i=0; i < shoes.length; ++i) {
    shoes[i] = "\"" + shoes[i] + "\"";
}
Set<String> shoesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(shoes));
```

Then use the set as you plan to:

```
itemSetList.add(shoesSet);
```

However, I have the feeling that you might be dealing with JSON or other similar data, in which case perhaps you should be using a parser which would handle the quotes automatically.

Comment: Hi Tim Biegeleisen, I don't really understand why you are adding `"` quotes to the `String` object? It seems the question did not say anything about adding quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Try to `split(",")` the String into an `String Array`, next add each `trim()` -ed `String` to a `HashSet` object, later you can add the `HashSet` object to your `List<Set<String>>`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String data = "Nike, Adidas, Reebok";
        String[] items = data.split(",");

        List<Set<String>> itemsetList = new ArrayList<>();

        Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String item : items)
            hashSet.add(item.trim());

        itemsetList.add(hashSet);

        for (Set<String> set : itemsetList)
        {
            for (String string : set)
                System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you would like a shorter version, 
Note that `split(",\\s")` splits on the comma followed by a space `,`. This is the same as `split(",")` followed by `trim()`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String data = "Nike, Adidas, Reebok";

        List<Set<String>> itemsetList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemsetList.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(data.split(",\\s"))));

        for (Set<String> set : itemsetList)
        {
            for (String string : set)
                System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful insight @Igoranze.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the data while adding them to the list:

```
itemSetList.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(data.split(","))));
```

Comment: This won't split properly, and you are missing quotes.

Comment: String data = "Nike, Adidas, Reebok";
List<Set<String>> itemSetList = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
itemSetList.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(data.split(";"))));
System.out.println(itemSetList);

Comment: I tried, and spitting only by comma left residual whitespace there.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that the string returned is the content of single field in your database. It much more looks like an aggregation of some kind.
I am right if there is a chance that the number of elements in this list changes

Therefore I also doubt that `List<Set<String>> itemsetList;` is the appropriate structure to store that values within the Java program.

---

Nevertheless my suggestion is to solve this problem on the database side by splitting the value list into individual columns in your SQL statement.

This will either give you one single name per result row (which is what I expect) or it gives you a fix number of columns per result row you can easily put into an HashSet.

---

I know that the suggestions of the others have less effort to implement, but in the long rung it will pay of to invest some time in proper data structures right from the beginning.

Comment: Thank for the advice Timothy. I am using a class that implements the Apriori algorithm for Market Basket Analysis and hence the use of a List containing sets which are the transaction items. The String is actually a single field as transaction items are stored together in my implementation.